# Python program to read text files and tabulate in excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, file, text

0 0.303 0.775  TestSet_0000.img
 sm       0.524

1 0.670 0.670  TestSet_0001.img
   sm       2.670

I would like to read the text file (above example is the data in txt file). I want to read sm value greater than 2.5 and tabulate that sm value in excel sheet along with the name (written as TestSet_ooxx.img).

For now I am able to read the whole text file and write it into xls sheet. But I need to only few information to be written in excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
import re
a = '''0 0.303 0.775 TestSet_0000.img
sm 0.524

1 0.670 0.670 TestSet_0001.img
sm 2.670

1 0.670 0.670 TestSet_0001.img
sm 2.570

1 0.670 0.670 TestSet_0001.img
sm 1.370

1 0.670 0.670 TestSet_0001.img
sm 2.91'''
res = re.findall('r'.+?\nsm [2-9].[5-9][0-9]*', a)
str = []
for i in res:
    str.append(i.split('\n')[0])
```

Comment: 0 0.303 0.775 TestSet_0000.img
sm 0.524

1 0.670 0.670 TestSet_0001.img
sm 2.670                                                                                                                                         This data is in text file. I want to write program to copy only values =>2.5 and previous line (TestSet_0001.img) to new excel sheet. The 2.5 should be in column B and TestSet_0001.img should be in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Open up each file, iterate through each line. Append to new file based on value after split of line.

```
with open("<FILENAME>.txt") as FileObj:
    for line in FileObj:
        x = line.strip().split()[1]
        if (x > "2.5"):
            file = open("<FILENAME>.csv","a")
            file.write(line)
            file.close
```

Comment: 0 0.303 0.775 TestSet_0000.img
sm 0.524

1 0.670 0.670 TestSet_0001.img
sm 2.670                                                                                                                                         This data is in text file. I want to write program to copy only values =>2.5 and previous line (TestSet_0001.img) to new excel sheet. The 2.5 should be in column B and TestSet_0001.img should be in column A.